# mysql bash escaping my single quotes

Tags: mysql, bash, escaping

I am trying to execute a mysql query from a shell script on Ubuntu 16. Let's call the variable $thing.

### Shell script

```
thing=stuff.whatever
mysql -h host -u superuser -ppassword123 --database bestdbever -e "update table set column1=1 where column2='$thing';"
```

---

where gets sent is this....

```
mysql -h host -u superuser -ppassword123 --database bestdbever -e "update table set column1=1 where column2='\''stuff.whatever'\'';'
```

When escaping the single quote, it sends

```
mysql -h host -u superuser -ppassword123 --database bestdbever -e "update table set column1=1 where column2=\'\''stuff.whatever\'\'';'
```

and then I cry.

Comment: Give a sample value which you are assigning to the variable ***thing***. I tried with a few and i am able to execute queries successfully.

Comment: sample: website.com

Comment: Command from script:
mysql --raw --batch -h $redacted -u $redacted -p$redacted --database $redacted -e "update domains set process = 7 where domain='$thing';"

Bash -x results:
mysql  -h <redacted> -u <redacted> -p<redacted> --database <redacted> -e 'update domains set process = 7 where domain=\'\''0003.link\'\'';'

Comment: Your command is not matching with the debugging output. You command is using *double quotes* ***-e "sql update query"***, but the debug output shows *single quotes* ***-e 'sql update query'***. which one is correct?

Comment: You are seeing the command I am sending and what stdout shows when I run it with bash -x. You are also correct that the command uses double quotes or single quotes and when bash -x shows is this horrible dumpsterfire:  \'\''

Comment: How is `''0003.link''` assigned to `thing`?